# How to ensure Unity does not rearrange the sub-meshes of a mesh on import?

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, mesh, maya, import

having a bit of a head scratcher problem here. I have my artist's making multiple unique meshes in Maya that contain 3 materials. Each material is assigned to a sub-mesh in a specific order. This order is identical across all the meshes being created. When bringing over these meshes to Unity, we have noticed that some meshes keep their material/sub-mesh order from Maya, and some do not. It's been making code generated material swaps a nightmare. So a few questions:

1.) What is Unity's logic when importing meshes and ordering the sub-meshes?

2.) Is there a simple way to make sure Unity does NOT reorder the sub-meshes/material order?

3.) Is there a way on Maya's side when exporting to make sure the sub-meshes/material order is as intended?

Any help or ideas is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What model format (e.g. FBX, OBJ) are you using when you export from Maya?

Comment: We're using FBX's.

Comment: Can you use [remapping](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FBXImporter-Materials.html)?

Comment: Remapping hasn't been working either. The order of the materials inside of remapping is correct in writing, but when looking at the model in the editor, each material is being applied to the wrong submesh. The order of the materials is correct, but the submeshes are not in that same order.

Comment: This sounds like something you should file a bug report for.